# Objects all doesn't give ms anything inside the view method

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I'm developing a new web app. I want to display data from the database to the html template. I don't get any errors but I don't get the data inside my views methode using 'Objects.all()'. When I tried the django shell it works.
I am using postgres database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4IjM.png)

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Catégorie(models.Model):
    désignation = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    Quantité_de_Stock = models.IntegerField()
    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    est_publié = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_de_modification = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.désignation

#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Catégorie

def index(request):
    Catégorie_list=Catégorie.objects.all()
    context = {
     'Catégorie_list':Catégorie_list, 
    }
    return render(request,'articles/Category.html',context)
#html
<div class="row">

                {% if articles %}
                    {% for category in Catégorie_list %}
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
                            <div class="card listing-preview">
                                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ category.photo_main.url }}" alt="">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="listing-heading text-center">
                                        <h4 class="text-primary" >{{ category.désignation }}</h4>

                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                    <a href="article.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Voir la catégorie</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}

                {% else %}
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>Aucune catégorie disponible</p>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}

            </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMMin.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm6nF.png)

Comment: Can you share your template please?

Comment: I added it now.

Comment: there is no articles in context

Comment: Articles exist inside the navBar's code

Comment: Do you see the else block or nothing appears? (images don't appear in my country)

Comment: the else block execute perfectly.

Comment: I tried other models but nothing appears just the else block

Comment: I already filled the database

Comment: you must add articles to context

Comment: articles is just the name of 'Id' inside (div) in the navbar and the name of the app installed. I have categories in the data base

Comment: when you use `{% if something %}` , something must be a context variable, not id etc.

Comment: You were right. Thank you verrrrrrrrry much

Comment: you are welcome :)